# How to read from a file where the filepath uses backward slashes?

Tags: node.js, fs

In node.js, if I try to read from a file with backward slashes in the link (using `fs` module), I get this

```
 Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, open 'C:\main\temp\config
1\folder\plugin\jquery-3.1.1.min.js'
    at Error (native)
  errno: -4068,
  code: 'EISDIR',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'C:\\main\\temp\\config1\\folder\\plugin\\jquery-3.1.1.min.js' }
```

node.js code:

```
fs.readFile('C:\main\temp\config1\folder\plugin\jquery-3.1.1.min.js', function (err, data) {

});
```

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Windows paths are supported by nodejs. You need to escape the backslashes:

```
fs.readFile('C:\\main\\temp\\config1\\folder\\plugin\\jquery-3.1.1.min.js', function (err, data) {

});
```

Comment: But before I pass the filepath to readFile, I use this `path.join("C:/hello", "/foo/bar");`, can I have path.join, automatically escape it for me?

Comment: @omega No you cannot because unescaped backslashes are syntax errors, not encoding errors, but you can use `path.join` to automatically add backslashes to your string. For example, `path.join('C:', 'Windows', 'hello')` results in `C:\Windows\hello`, but you will need to do `path.join('C:\\Windows', 'hello')` if you do it that way.